# Specific subtotals using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, subtotal

[image]

Above is an example of input data I extract from a database. Column A has multiple levels (named L1, L2, L3, L4, L5). Column B has values. The way it functions is, 
L2 = Sum of all L1 above it, till you encounter another L2 above. 
L3 = sum of all L2 above it till you encounter another L3 above.

Similar for L4. The final level is L5 which has sum of all L4 in the column.

Also, sometimes there is a standalone L2 (for which no L1 breakup details are available), and it has to be considered as it is. Example – Cell B10, which has a standalone value of 2, and there is immediately another L2 above it in Cell B9, which is a sum of L1 above it

The issue is sometimes the data is incorrect and an L2 might not be the sum of all L1 above it (like a L1 row might have been missed by the database). I need to verify in column C if such an error has taken place.

So my output in column C should have values same as Column B for L2, L3, L4, L5 if there is no error. Or different values, if there is error.

The range is dynamic and runs into hundreds of rows.

Any macro or pre-existing excel formula can accomplish this?

I would be very grateful for any help/ code or pointers I can get for this problem.

The following is part code which I created. Need your assistance for the comments part. Thank you for the assistance.

```
Sub Ttals()
lastrow = Worksheets("EMEA").Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print lastrow
For i = 2 To lastrow
If Cells(i, 1) = "L1" Then
    Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 2) 'This is pasting L1 values from column B/2 to column C/3

ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "L2" Then
'Insert a function to search rows above this cell for values:
'If immediately above - L2/L3/L4/L5/L6 are encountered, paste value from column B/2 for this row
'If immediately above L1 is encountered, keep going above till more L1 are encoutered,
'and when any other L are encountered, stop going up and take a sum of all L1 in this range and post the sum

ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "L3" Then
'Insert similar function which I can modify myself once I get the above function for L2

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this more of a database concern?  I may be confused as to where the data is coming from, but it seems like it would make more sense to fix the source query(s) than to try and "massage" the bad data that you get back from it.

Comment: Hi @Comintern - Good observation. However, I don't have control over the database and accordingly, have to do these checks at my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula you can use:

`{=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))>1,IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()),A1)=1,SUMIFS(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()),INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()),"L"&VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))-1),SUMIFS(INDIRECT("B"&LARGE(IF($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())=A1,ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))-MIN(ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())))+1),2)&":B"&ROW()),INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(IF($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())=A1,ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))-MIN(ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())))+1),2)&":A"&ROW()),"L"&VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))-1)),B1)}`

Tried different things to check value of row above but array formula has gotten the better of me, so below is a check for 0:

`{=IF(IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))>1,IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()),A1)=1,SUMIFS(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()),INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()),"L"&VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))-1),SUMIFS(INDIRECT("B"&LARGE(IF($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())=A1,ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))-MIN(ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())))+1),2)&":B"&ROW()),INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(IF($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())=A1,ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))-MIN(ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())))+1),2)&":A"&ROW()),"L"&VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))-1)),B1)=0,B1,IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))>1,IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()),A1)=1,SUMIFS(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()),INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()),"L"&VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))-1),SUMIFS(INDIRECT("B"&LARGE(IF($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())=A1,ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))-MIN(ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())))+1),2)&":B"&ROW()),INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(IF($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())=A1,ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))-MIN(ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW())))+1),2)&":A"&ROW()),"L"&VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))-1)),B1)}`

Notice it's an array formula! Paste in cel `C1` as such and drag it down.

It's quite a lengthy one :P

Comment: Hi JvdV, Thank you for the detailed array formula and replying so quickly. I ran the formula on my sheet, and while it works fine mostly, it doesn't compute for the consecutive L2, like cell C10 still reflects 0 instead of 2. PS: If you are trying to rerun the formula, please correct the error 'RICHT' to 'RIGHT' in the last section. Also, if splitting L1 between "L" and "1" is a chore, I can easily change L1 to 1/ L2 to 2 and so on in the sheet to make it easier. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I might have another look at it sometime soon. P.S. the typo is cause I'm working with the dutch function names, having to translate them after :)

Comment: Hi @JvdV Noted. Any chance you modified the formula? I am trying to add another If condition, but it isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: @dark_horizon, I have spend some time and tried different things, but the easiest is to check if above formula returns `0`. So add an `IF` statement like: `=IF(...full above formula...=0,B1,...again the full formula from above)`

Comment: @dark_horizon, please if this answered your question, than mark as answered!

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works perfectly. Am surprised such a complex calculation is done by only formula and not macro. You are a genius. Hope I will get a chance to help you someday. Thanks again.